# Unittesting with translations

Tags: python, google-app-engine, internationalization

I'm trying to unittest code where I use `webapp2_extras.i18n.lazy_gettext`, but I don't always want to test requests. When I test code where I use that method, I get the following Exception:

```
AssertionError: Request global variable is not set.
```

Can I test translations without using webapp2?

Comment: you can mock the Request